# Is this definition of splitting field pleonastic?

Tags: splitting-field

I found this definition of a splitting field but I am wondering if the second condition does not implies the first one.

[image: Definition of splitting field]

If $L$ is generated over $K$ by the zeros of the polynomials of the family, does not it follows that such zeros belong to $L$ and so every $f_i$ splits into linear factors?

Comment: I don't think it's really redundant because "the zeros" might just refer to those zeros that happen to be in L, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is generated by the zeros of $(x^2+1)(x^2-2)$ which lie in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

If (2) does not hold, there would be infinitely many "splitting fields". The condition (2) guarantees that L is the smallest field in which the function family factors into linear factors.

Comment: I asked if the first condition were superfluous. I think the second one it sufficente.